# Use UIAutomation and other Instruments like Allocation

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, memory-management, instruments

How can we use more than one instruments at the same time ?

I'm currently using UIAutomation with a very long test, and I would like to use also the allocation instruments.

I can't find any reference on how to combine a new instruments with a current one already running.

The Build new instrument menu option is not what I want, I think.

thanks,

m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the instrument library, which contains the available instruments. Choose Window > Library or click the Library button in the toolbar to open the instrument library. To add an instrument to a trace, drag the instrument from the library to the instrument list on the left side of the trace document window.